# Feature stapling vs Site Definitions

Tags: sharepoint, sitedefs

I curious of what you’re experiences are one the user of site definition compared to feature stapling. In a video on Channel 9 Ted Patterson explains that feature stapling is the way to go. It would be nice to know of some experiences other SharePoint experts have.

Are you all using Feature stapling or are there areas where Site Definitions is a better choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it purely scenario dependent Feature stapling is good if we have to work on some existing site definition like third party or OOTB. but if its a custom solution or my own custom product based on SharePoint i would still like to go with site definitions

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, we should avoid using Site Definitions and use Features for all the custom development/provisioning/customizations cause they are much more flexible & extensible.

I have worked for Microsoft on many sharepoint projects including the 2007 and 2010 version of the http://www.microsoft.com/sharepoint public iste and almost all the customizations and provisiong was done via Feature Staplers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of customizations, then site definition is the only route to go.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it's hard to maintain a complex site definition. The best way to go is create a very minimal site definition than staple the features you need. It also promotes modularity (by using features) and reusability.